# Hunter x Hunter Song?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

I really like the music in Hunter X Hunter and have found all but ONE song.  If someone could help me find this one it would be greatly appreciated!!  Here is an example of what the song is; in episode 86 at 12:08 https://www.crunchyroll.com/hunter-x-hunter/episode-86-promise-x-and-x-reunion-623015

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The track is called Bisky's theme. It is an unreleased track btu you can find it on youtube.
https://youtu.be/pMDtI7oi8Mo